# Automated localhost homepage - show link for each folder inside home dir

Tags: apache, localhost, lamp

I have just finished configuring my LAMP environment on new macbook but would like to go a little further.

My home dir is as follows:

```
var/www/
    site1.com
    site2.com
    site3.com
```

I would like my localhost homepage to automatically display a link for each folder within my home directory. Could anyone point in my the right direction for a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

create links to each folder in your homepage

```
<a href="http://localhost/site1.com">site1</a>
<a href="http://localhost/site2.com">site2</a>
<a href="http://localhost/site3.com">site3</a>
```

Comment: Hmmm, this is not really "automated" is it. I ended up using PHP's Glob for this, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

I used PHP for this, making use of "glob"

```
                        <?php foreach (glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $filename) {
                            if ($filename != "project_thumbs") {
                            echo '<a className="project" href="/'.$filename.'/"><img src="project_thumbs\/'.$filename.'.png"></img><h3>'.$filename.'</h3></a>';
                            }
                        } ?>
```